How to get reference to a MapAdvancedMarker in my component
I am using the @angular/google-maps package with several Advanced Markers (since MapMarkers are deprecated):
<google-map
  height="400px"
  width="750px"
  [center]="center"
  [zoom]="zoom"
  (mapInitialized)="onMapInitialized($event)">
    @for (position of markerPositions; track position) {
      <map-advanced-marker 
        #mapAdvancedMarker="mapAdvancedMarker" 
        [position]="position" />
    }
</google-map>

How can I get the reference to a specific marker in my component in order to update its content, position, ... or to trigger a click event?

Add a reference parameter to your markers? What have you tried and what did not work and why?

Thanks for your time. I tried both ViewChild and ViewChildren in combination with adding #advMarker="mapAdvancedMarker" to the <map-advanced-marker> but I was not able to get a hand on the element.

Apparently, the (mapInitialized)="onMapInitialized($event)" callback function is not reliable in order to check for the ViewChild reference (as it keeps being undefined). Hence, when checking it in AfterViewInit, it is set up and all works fine and I can do whatever I want with it.
